# cannot retrieve jquery set value through php

Tags: php, jquery, model

I have set a value to a hidden input field through jquery.This is my jquery:-

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  var businessid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('businessid');
  $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="businessID"]').val(businessid);              
});
```

Now I want to echo the value of hidden field using PHP. I tried many things, including:

```
if (!empty($_POST['businessID']))
```

and

```
echo (isset($_POST['businessID']) ? $_POST['businessID'] : '');
```

However it didn't work. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you sure `businessid` contains the value you expect? How are you sending the data to PHP? If it's a standard form POST are you sure that the hidden field is contained within the `<form>` element? Are you sending a GET instead? There's not quite enough information in the question to help you. Seeing a more complete sample of the HTML and JS along with the PHP would help us diagnose any issues.

Comment: why doesn't it work? is the field empty? have you checked wether your jquery code does set a value to the field? (I sometimes use text inputs for development and only when I'm sure it works I change them to hidden inputs, that makes it easier to debug)